# Convert int to two bytes in hex?

Tags: dart

Context: I'm working on a lighting protocol converter for architectural LED matrices and need to encode byte strings in a very specific way for the headers to be recognized by my hardware.

Q: How can I convert an int into two bytes such that I can then use them separately?

Example:

I want to convert

```
var aDynamicValue = 511 //where value will range from 0-511
```

to a list like: `[0x01, 0xFF]`

Such that I can then

```
<BytesBuilder> magicString.add(--the bytes above--)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use bit shifting together with logical `AND` to mask out all but first 8 bits. Pseudo code:

```
a = 511;
byte1 = a & 0xff;
byte2 = (a >> 8) & 0xff;
```

Answer (score 12):

typed_data and `int.toRadixString(16)` can be used to get hex from integers:

```
final list = new Uint64List.fromList([511]);
final bytes = new Uint8List.view(list.buffer);
final result = bytes.map((b) => '0x${b.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')}');
print('bytes: ${result}');
```

Comment: For anyone trying this, you will need to import this package: import 'dart:typed_data';